# Session does not end properly

Tags: php, html, authentication, session

So normally my session should end when I press logout button on my page but when I go to the previous page via the button (top left). I just go back to my page logged in..

```
This is my login page code
<?php 

session_start();
$errors = array();
if(isset($_POST["name"]) and isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123", "whoosh") or die("No connection made: ".mysqli_connect_error());

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];


    if (empty($name)) { array_push($errors, "Ename is required"); }
    if (empty($password)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE name='$name' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

        if ($user) { // if user exists
        if ($user['name'] === $name and $user['password'] === $password) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user['id'];
            header('location: mainsite.php');
        }
    }


    }
}
```

?>

```
This is the code I put on my main site thats allows me to logout.
  <?php
    session_start();


   if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
     $_SESSION['name'] = null;
    header('Location:http://leopard.med.agfa.be/leopard/website/logIn.php');
   }

   session_destroy();
 ?>
```

So, why is my session not working properly and doesnt log out completely?

Comment: set session_destroy(); befor header('Location..

Comment: _“I just go back to my page logged in”_ - probably rather the _cached_ version of your logged-in page? What happens if you explicitly _reload_ it at that point? _“This is the code I put on my main site thats allows me to logout.”_ - why is session_destroy _outside_ of that if?

Comment: You have to set session_destroy() in if(isset($_GET['logout'])) condition and before header('Location') statement.

Comment: @YounesZaidi Did not work. :(

Comment: Like this?; if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    $_SESSION['name'] = null;
 session_destroy();
    header('Location:http://leopard.med.agfa.be/leopard/website/logIn.php');
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one! I dont see any where you passing name to session.

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    // Initialize the session
       session_start();
    // Unset all of the session variables
       session_unset();
       $_SESSION = array();
    // Destroy the session.
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
    // Redirect to login page
        header('Location:http://leopard.med.agfa.be/leopard/website/logIn.php');
        exit();
}
```

Note: I used both `unset()` and `destroy()` functions you can use one.

Comment: would you please `echo $_GET['logout']` to see if you realy get the button clicked or from url (whatever)?.

Comment: Can it be that in my navbar i got this code to logout; <a style="float:right;" href="?logout=true">Log out</a>

Comment: Change your link like this  `<a href="logout.php" title="Logout" style="float:right;">Logout</a>` and remove `if(isset($_GET['logout'])){ }` see if it works

Comment: I dont have a logout.php, but when i changed to to login.php it unfortunately didnt work again

Comment: your code should look like this `<a style="float:right;" href="the_page_your_logout_codes_in.php?logout=true">Log out</a>` *I dont have a logout.php* How do you log out then ? did you add the codes in answer in to login.php?

Answer (score 1):

Change the logout script to this:

```php
<?php

if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    // null the _SESSION
    $_SESSION = null;
    // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_unset();
    // destroy session data in storage
    session_destroy();
    // last, redirect
    header('Location:http://leopard.med.agfa.be/leopard/website/logIn.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: This answer will end up all started sessions in website, (Any logged in users).

Comment: well thats odd... Can you dump domething inside ```isset($_GET['logout'])``` to ensure that you even enter the script?